# How to remove after dash all digits in this String?

Tags: dart, flutter

Example: **1007 Rm: Suite (S)**

I want to get only **1007 Rm**

How to get it?

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/String/split.html

Comment: What is "after dash word"? Especially in this example.

Comment: My app bar title to `1007 Rm: Suite` But I need to pass only `1007 Rm`

Comment: @Antoniossss I edited my heading...Sorry for bad english

Comment: @Eugene can to give example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String str = '1007 Rm: Suite (S)';
  str = str.split(':')[0];
  print(str); // 1007 Rm
```